# Go lang test events listener?

Tags: events, testing, go, listener

This question is about **Go language testing**. As you probably know most of mainstream languages have their own xUnit frameworks. Most of these frameworks have an ability to listen to test run events (e.g. test case started, test case finished, test failed and so on). This is often called **test event listener** and is mainly used when writing third-party extensions for frameworks.

My question: **is there any similar way to attach to standard Go language testing framework events (http://golang.org/pkg/testing/)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box, but it shouldn't be hard to rig up yourself. Any function named `init` is guaranteed to be run before anything else, and that's true for tests as well.

In your test file:

```
var listener pkg.EventListener
func init() {
    pkg.SetupMyFramework()
    listener = pkg.Listener()
}
```

Then in any test

```
func TestXxx(t *testing.T) {
    listener.Dispatch(pkg.MakeEvent("TestXxx", pkg.TestStarted))

    err := DoSomething()
    if err != nil {
        listener.Dispatch(pkg.MakeEvent("TestXxx", pkg.TestFailed))
        t.Fatal("Test failed")
    }

    listener.Dispatch(pkg.MakeEvent("TestXxx", pkg.TestPassed))
}
```

You can, of course, extend this however you want (using channels, making wrapper functions around `Fatal` to make this less verbose, etc), but that's the gist of how you can integrate it.

Comment: Wouldn't it create a lot of copy paste in test logic? I'm looking for a single entry point like JUnit RunListener http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html.

Comment: @vania-pooh You're not going to get a simple solution because such a thing just simply isn't integrated into the `go test` framework. Any solution is going to require a little extra hooking in yourself.

Comment: No problem, but so far as we're implementing a testing report the main idea is to make sure that in order to use this report anyone should make the minimum number of changes in his tests.

Comment: @vania-pooh See my edit, I wrote a really simple package that should do what you want with only minimal hooking. Pretty much the only thing you need to do is register listeners in `init` and start functions with `t := testevents.Start(some arguments)` followed by `defer t.Done()`.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. It would help to know what you are trying to accomplish such that you need this capability?

Comment: «...mainly used when writing third-party extensions for frameworks.» ? If someone is about to write a unit testing package for Go on steroids, this would be a straightforward question to answer.  On the other hand, if one writes such a framework, they have full control over the lifecycles of their testcases anyway...

Comment: We're working on a testing report and did the first attempt to implement data collecting adapter for Go. The main idea is to be able to collect the following events: test suite started, test case method started, test suite finished and so on.

Answer (score 0):

go1.10 is going to be released soon, and one new feature is `go test -json` (release notes https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.10#test).

Using `go test -json` you can parse the test output and send it to a third party framework.